# const&& binding to ref in lambda capture: clang vs gcc?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

In the following code:

```
int foo() {
  int a = 5;
  auto l = [&r = std::move(std::as_const(a))] { return r; };
  return l();  
}
```

clang compiles just fine

gcc produces error.

```
error: cannot capture 'std::move<const int&>((* & std::as_const<int>(a)))' by reference
```

I need community help to argue about this case from C++ standard point of view: who is correct in C++20 and why exactly.

From [expr.prim.lambda.capture] not clear to me if this clause:

> An init-capture without ellipsis behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form "auto init-capture"

means that clang is right? If yes then why removing as_const makes this an error for both?

[code example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/xxv5aqr71)

Comment: `std::move(std::as_const(a))` There is no reason to ever do this. You cannot move from a `const` object, so you are in effect lying about what is happening.

Comment: This code is highly minimized in reality it was hmm... bigger. And I assure you const rvalue references are perfect and in some kind sensible objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a GCC bug. The init-capture should behave as if declaring a corresponding variable with `auto` prefixed and which is then captured (exactly as in your quote from the standard):

```
auto &r = std::move(std::as_const(a));
```

This would deduce `auto` to `const int` so that the variable has type `const int&` and initialization would be well-formed because the initializer is a rvalue of type `const int` which a `const` lvalue reference can bind to directly.

However `std::move` has no effect here and the result would be identical without it. (`std::move` on a `const`  type basically never makes sense.)

---

It fails without `as_const` because then `auto` will be deduced to just `int` so that the variable has type `int&`. You are then trying to initialize it from an rvalue (the result of `std::move`) which is not allowed when initializing non-`const` lvalue references.

Comment: Sorry but std::move makes perfect sense here: it creates const rvalue reference from const lvalue reference. I afraid your answer lacks what I expected: link to standard and explanation why removal of std::as_const (preserving move) makes it bug for both.

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov See edit. I don't know for which part you want a standard reference. There isn't really anything lambda-specific here. The behavior is the same as a usual variable declaration `auto &r = std::move(std::as_const(a));`. There isn't actually anything special here except that `const` rvalues are rare.

Comment: Ok, I got it, you are right.